# SharePoint 2010 column validation alphanumeric

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to use OOTB SharePoint column validation to allow only `alphanumeric` values. How can I do that?

I saw some formula online such as one below but as we have long column name. 1024 charter limit is exceeded and also below formula is specifically checking to NOT have special characters instead of allowing only alphanumeric.

For example I don't want to allow - and _ the formula would be like below:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("_",Title)),TRUE))
```

Is it possible to combine `ISTEXT` and `ISNUMBER` to allow only alphanumeric?

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't do this out of the box.

An alternative is to use the `PreSaveAction` JavaScript function so that the form is validated when the user clicks the Save button - not sure if JavaScript is an option for you though.

The JavaScript would grab the value of the field(s) to validate, e.g. `Title`, check whether the value is alphanumeric (you can use a regular expression in your JavaScript to check this, e.g. `[0-9a-zA-Z]`), and if not, stop the save action.

Find out more about the `PreSaveAction` function [here](http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/28/validation-on-sharepoint-forms-part-four/) and [here](http://sharepointwings.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/javascript-presaveaction-in-sharepoint.html?_sm_au_=itVTnDNtfNjjF76M).

Answer (score 0):

You would find [this](http://3sharp.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-in-sharepoint-lists/) article useful. It uses infopath to validate the data using RegEx.

I don't think there is any OOTB way of doing what you are trying.